# Visual Studio: How can I see the same file in two separate tab groups?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to be able to edit one method while looking at another method in the same file, as reference.
Can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open two instances of a file in single Visual Studio session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-single-visual-studio-session)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, @nawfal. Either way, the solutions in the other answer don't work in SSMS (v17.4).

Answer (score 354):

You can open the file in another tab (`Window` -> `New Window`).

Doing so you have two copies of the same file. Then you can right-click the tab bar and select `New Vertical Tab Group` (or `New Horizontal Tab Group`, the one you like more).

Hope I understood you question..

Comment: VS 2013 made it simpler - Window -> Split

Comment: True, it splits only vertically though

Comment: Just wanted to add a keyboard shortcut for this: 1) ```Alt + w,n``` for ```New Window``` and ```Alt+w,v``` for ```New vertical tab group```

Comment: To get the window arrangement I want, I usually just grab any source file from the source window, drag it out so it's free floating, and then you can use the "target" icons in the middle to dock it wherever you want, creating a second tab group.  Then do the Window -> New Window, and finally drag the new view of your file to the second tab group.  Yes, I do admit it's a bit of work, but I've done it often enough it's pretty much muscle memory by now.

Comment: What a shame. Notepad++ is doing it more professional than M$ Visual Studie. After > 1 Decade, we still have to do 5 steps, just because M$ is not willing to do the homework and offer a "Open File in other Document Group" command.

Answer (score 100):

> Be **on** the tab you want to duplicate,
> then click in the **menu bar** at the top on
> `Window` > `New Window`

Finally drag & drop the second window to the the left or right side to show both views next to each other.
Et voila, there you have it `:)`

[image: image insturction 1]
[image: image insturction 2]

## EDIT

**It seems that this function is not implemented in all version of VS.**
In my case (`V 15.4.2 (2017)`, `V 15.9.7 (2017)` & `V 16.2.5 (2019)`) it just works fine.

[image: Version 15.9.7]

Comment: This does not work in VS 2015.  It says that that tab is open and then closes it and reopen it.

Comment: @RyanLee it does work for me, i haven't changed any settings, don't know where the problem could be.

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work in SSMS v17.4, for the same reason as stated by @RyanLee.

Comment: Works on 2017. And to complete the answer - Once you have the new tab, drag it and dock it to the side of the original tab

Comment: In VS 2017 v15.9.3 there is no New Window under Window menu when you're on the tab.

Comment: @JasonWillett please take a look at my edit, as you can see it just works fine on a bit older build.

Comment: Works in Version 16.7.2

Answer (score 81):

Only vertically that I'm aware.  When looking at the code, right above the vertical scroll bar is a small rectangle, drag it down to get a split view of the file.

Answer (score 46):

You simply use the small drag arrows icon at the top right corner of your file window as depicted in the following screenshots:

[image: Before dragging]

[image: After dragging]

Comment: tab groups is a vertical split, you have demonstrated a horizontal split.

Comment: What is the keyboard shortcut for switching between this?

Answer (score 21):

**1) View the same document side-by-side (with a fix for Visual Studio 2017)**

It is possible to do this using `New Window` and `New Vertical Tab Group`, however, in my Visual Studio 2017 the `New Window` command was **missing** from the `Window` menu. To use it, first you must **add** the command to a menu or assign a shortcut to it.

To add `New Window` to your `Window` menu follow this sequence, starting with the `Tools` menu:

`Tools` > `Customize` > `Commands` > `Menu Bar` > `Window` > `Add Command` > `Window` > `New Window`

FYI In the `Commands` step you decide where to put the `New Window` command. The sequence I gave above puts it unceremoniously at the top of the `Window` menu.

**To view the same document side-by-side**

1. Open the document you want to view side-by-side
2. Select your recently added `New Window` command (perhaps it's in `Window` > `New Window`)
3. Right click the new tab and select `New Vertical Tab Group` or select that command from the `Window` menu

**2) View the same document above-one-another**

If you wish to view the same document in two views on top of each other use the `Window` > `Split` command or click-and-drag the double-arrow at the top of the scroll bar for any window.

**3) Get creative**

FYI You can even combine the two view options to have three, four or even more views of the same document on a particularly wide monitor. On mine (2560 x 1080) I can comfortably get three side-by-side views going **and** split them vertically, if desired.
[image: multiple panes]

Comment: This doesn't work in SSMS v17.4. When clicking _New window_, it will ask me whether to close to current window or not.

Answer (score 6):

One can install [VsVim](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) extension and `:sp` `:vsp` does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 15 you can just click inside the document and then "Window → Split"

Answer (score 0):

Since this is quite old and there's a new more efficient way of doing this:
While in Visual Studio open document you want to see in split view and click on:
`Window > Split`