# Open two instances of a file in a single Visual Studio session

Tags: visual-studio, editor

I have a file, *xyz.cpp*. I want to open two instances of this file in Visual studio (BTW, I am using Visual Studio 2005). Why would I want to do so? I want to compare two sections of the same file side by side. I know workarounds such as:

1. Make a copy of the file. But the problem is that it's not elegant, and I don't want to  make copies every time I am faced with this.
2. I can split the window into two. The problem with split it that I can split it horizontally only. The result of a horizontal split is that the right half of my screen is white space.

If I were able to split it vertically or open two instances of the same file, it would increase the number of lines of code I can compare.

Comment: If you want to just simply compare parts of the file, you could use Window | Split which will split the file horizontally from the middle.

Comment: Related post - [Visual Studio: How can I see the same file in two separate tab groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444382/465053)

Comment: Note to potential answerers: This question is about [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio), ** ******** ***not*** ******** ** [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), AKA `code`, `Code`, `CODE`, `the code`, `Visual Code`, `visual studio code`, `Visualstudio Code`, `vs code`, `vs Code`, `Vs code`, `Vs Code`, `VS code`, `VS Code`, `VS CODE`, `VS code studio`, `VS Core`, `vs-code`, `VS-Code`, `vs.code`, `vsc`, `VSC`, `VSC Code`, `VSCod`, `vscode`, `Vscode`, `VsCode`, and `VSCode` (thanks, Microsoft marketing). They are in no way the same thing.

Comment: Candidate Visual Studio *** ***Code*** *** ones: *[How can multiple files be opened in Visual Studio Code (VSC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827846/how-can-multiple-files-be-opened-in-visual-studio-code-vsc)* and *[How do I open the same file side by side in a single Visual Studio Code session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674275/how-do-i-open-the-same-file-side-by-side-in-a-single-visual-studio-code-session)*.

Answer (score 1105):

### Visual Studio

Here's how to do it...

1. Select the tab you want two copies of
2. Select menu *Window* → *New Window* from the menu.

[image]

3. Right click the new tab and select *New Vertical Tab Group*

[image]

If *New Window* is not listed in the *Window menu note that the command does exist, even as of Visual Studio 2017. Add it to the *Window* menu using menu *Tools* → *Customize* → *Commands*. At that point decide where to put the *New Window* command and select *Add Command*.

### VS Code

In Visual Studio Code version 1.25.1 and later

**Way 1**

You can simply left click on your file in the side-panel (explorer) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Way 2**

Simply right click on your file in the Visual Studio Code side-panel (explorer) and select the first option *open to the side*.

Comment: You can only do this for certain file types ... for example, you can't have two windows open on the same .xaml file. Which is a bummer, cause that's what I want to do!

Comment: Also not working for vb files. :-( It seems to depend on the specific editor, whether it's possible or not.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth See [Luke's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-single-visual-studio-session/7396899#7396899) It enables the feature for VB (in VS 2010 at least).

Comment: @Shlomi.A. Try [Luke's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-single-visual-studio-session/7396899#7396899)

Comment: Well...you can just click Window -> Split in VS 2012

Comment: @TheMentor it splits horizontaly :/ And can be splitted only once :/

Comment: @TheMentor - he wants it split vertically

Comment: For XAML in WPF the New Window option is just not there.

Comment: Once you have the two panels: Is it possible to always display open files twice? Meaning: Once you change the displayed file in panel A, then panel B automatically refreshes and shows the same file displayed in panel A and vice versa?

Comment: This method works, but on my VS 2010 the shortcut [Ctrl] [Shift] [N] was bound to File > New > Project

Comment: It doesn't work in VS 2015, That menu is disabled. I can split it in horizontally though. http://prntscr.com/d8e9fm

Comment: @GeorgiKovachev - just tried in VS2015 - works fine for C# files - as mentioned in the comments it's not available for all file types - check out Lukes answer to enable it for your cshtml files

Comment: VS 2015 Enterprise Update 1: This works for .js files now

Comment: _Select Window > New Window from the menu_ .... ok I am not a native English speaker, but I woudn't have ever guessed that "New Window" would open another instance of the currently active child window. Brilliant!

Comment: New Window is absent in VS2017 Version 15.9.3 for C++ (but was perhaps working in earlier VS2017 release??). Had to come here for this simple fix!!

Comment: @Andreas I am a native speaker and I never would have guessed either.

Comment: this is old but it works!

Answer (score 70):

For Visual Basic, HTML and JScript and RDL Expression, the `Window > New Window` option mentioned in [PaulB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-single-visual-studio-session/772159#772159) is disabled.
However an option can be changed in the Registry to enable the menu item.

All other languages do not restrict to a single code window so you can use [PaulB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-single-visual-studio-session/772159#772159) without editing the registry.

**Enabling New Window in Windows Registry.**<sup>[[1](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/05/17/visual-studio-window-new-window.aspx)] [[2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/20/multiple-views-of-the-same-document-window-vstipenv0016.aspx)]</sup>

1. Go to the following registry key. This example is for Basic (Visual Basic), but the key is also there for HTML, JScript and RDL Expression.

   - 64-bit OS: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\Language Services\Basic`
   - 32-bit OS: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\Language Services\Basic`
2. Find the value `Single Code Window Only` and do one of the following:

   - Set it to 0
   - Rename the value
   - Delete the value (**use caution**!)

This will enable the "New Window" menu item, but it may still not be visible in the menu.

**Adding Menu Item**

To actually see the New Window menu item I had to add it back into the menu:

- Tools > Customize... > Commands > Add Command...
- Select 'Menu Bar' the select the 'Window' menu in the dropdown
- Add Command... > Window > New Window > OK

**Restoring Registry Value**
Copy-paste this to notepad, save as a .reg file and import the file into your registry to restore the initial setting.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\Language Services\Basic]
"Single Code Window Only"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: No need to edit the registry for C# files as the 'New Window' menu item should be already enabled for C# files (in VS 2010). You only need to do this for VB, HTML or JScript. According to [this MS Connect issue report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559243/enable-the-windows-new-window-feature-for-visual-basic) any issues with this are fixed for VB, you just need to remove or rename the registry entry to enable the feature.

Comment: This works in Visual Basic 2010 Express as well, I'm happy to report. The registry key is slightly different: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VBExpress\10.0\Languages\Language Services\Basic].

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Tried restarting VS2010, will give it another chance after rebooting computer... (who knows how are registry entries read/stored/updated)

Comment: I just tested this (I guess my registry key got overwritten by updates or something). I didn't require a reboot. I changed the key with VS2010 running, 'New Window' still greyed out. Then closed VS2010 and opened VS2010 and 'New Window' is available.

Comment: The first link in my answer says _"The feature was put in, but not fully tested. So it was disabled."_ After using it for a while I can see why. After a while the menus at the top (the ones that list the class members) stop working properly or are just empty. Does that happen with C#?

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Languages\Language Services\Basic
Editing the RegEdit "Single Code Window Only"=0
sucess! 
Worked in Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

Comment: In VS2010, flipping the registry bit for JScript does allow a second tab to be opened for a JavaScript file (yay), but nothing except whiteness is rendered in each tab (boo).

Comment: NOTE: Don't attempt this hack. Like @gWiz said it doesn't work, and also after changing this my visual studio 2010 started behaving weirdly, displaying files wrong in the splits. I believe the registry flags are there for a reason...

Comment: @andersand, where you able to revert after things went wrong, or was it a permanent problem?

Comment: My VS is working fine now (at least AFAICT, I'm not using all features, and I do use resharper). I checked my registry now, and I have the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\Language Services\JScript\Single Code Window Only set to 1.

Answer (score 54):

Go to *menu* → *Windows* → *New Window*:

[image]

Answer (score 25):

You can use the *Windows* → *New Window* option to duplicate the current window. See more at: *[Why I like Visual Studio 2010? Undock Windows](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/why-i-visual-studio-2010-undock-windows#sthash.UTUQg8au.dpuf)*

Answer (score 24):

Open the file (if you are using multiple tab groups, make sure your file is selected).

Menu *Window* → *Split*
(alternately, there's this tiny nub just above the editor's vertical scroll bar - grab it and drag down)

This gives you two (horizontal) views of the same file. Beware that any edit-actions will reflect on both views.

Once you are done, grab the splitter and drag it up all the way (or menu *Window* → *Remove Split*).

Comment: (Sri: sorry, 'horizontal' as in the views' rows are aligned ... or one view above the other).

AFAIK, vertical (side-by-side) views are not possible.

Comment: Appears not to have read OP, where he mentions he is aware of this very thing.

Answer (score 22):

How to open two instances of the same file side by side in Visual Studio 2019:

1. Open the file.
2. Click *Window* → *New Window*.
3. A new window should be open with the same file.
4. Click on *Window* → *New Vertical Document Group*.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Based on this, can also perform this using keyboard shortcuts: Alt+W,N,Alt+W,V

Answer (score 14):

With the your file opened, go to command window (menu *View* → *Other Windows* → *Command window*, or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)

Type:

```
Window.NewWindow
```

And then

```
Window.NewVerticalTabGroup
```

worked for me (Visual Studio 2017).

Or using menus:

Menu *Window* → *New Window*

Menu *Window* → *New vertical tap group*

Comment: The menu seems disabled now for C# files, but the command window still works.

Answer (score 10):

[Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-a-single-visual-studio-session/7396899#7396899) didn't work for me. The 'New Window' command was already listed in the customize settings, but not showing up in the .js tabs context menu, despite deleting the registry setting.

So I used:

Tools

Customize...

Keyboard...

Scroll down to select Window.NewWindow

And I pressed and assigned the shortcut keys, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

That worked for me.

==== EDIT ====

Well, 'worked' was too strong. My keyboard shortcut does indeed open another tab on the same JavaScript file, but rather unhelpfully it does not render the contents; it is just an empty white window! You may have better luck.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me for VS2012/VB.net. Opened Tools - options - (under environment)keyboard - select visual basic 6 from dropdown - select Window.NewWindow from command list - pressed ctrl + n, ctrl + w

Answer (score 5):

*Window* menu, *New Horizontal/Vertical Tab Group* there will do, I think.

Comment: AFAI see, You can't open the same file in different tab groups

Answer (score 4):

When working with Visual Studio 2013 and VB.NET I found that you can quite easily customize the menu and add the "New Window" command - there is no need to mess with the registry!

God only knows why Microsoft chose not to include the command for some languages...?

Comment: Worked easily for me! Menu **Tools** > **Customize**. Then in **Commands** tab, select **Window** in the first dropdown, then click **Add Command** button and voilà! (Visual Studio 2019)

Answer (score 4):

For newer versions (such as Visual Studio 2017)

- Select the window you want to duplicate.
- Go to the window tab and click on split at the top of the list.
- When you are done, click it again to toggle it off.

Comment: A window split in two halves is not the same as two windows.

Answer (score 2):

For file types, where the same file **can't** be opened in a vertical tab group (for example .vb files) you can

- Open **2 different instances of Visual Studio**
- Open the same file in each instance
- Resize the IDE windows & place them side by side to achieve your layout.

If you save to disk in one instance though, you'll have to reload the file when you switch to the other. Also if you make edits in both instances, you'll have to resolve on the second save. Visual Studio prompts you in both cases with various options. You'll simplify your life a bit if you edit in only the one instance.

Comment: @Odrade - Can you point me to the correct answer that works for all types of files...

Comment: @Jason Ok, but it's still incorrect to state that you can't open the same file multiple times to to side-by-side comparison.  This is clearly possible, at least for .cs files.

Comment: @Odrade You are right. I've edited to try and correct that. Letting you know in case you want to remove comments based on previous versions.

Comment: @Odrade Got around to trying [Luke's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-single-visual-studio-session/7396899#7396899) It is far better than opening two instances of VS for VB users and has my upvote.

Comment: This seems the only working workaround for html files, where the registry edit just gives a blank second window

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of Visual Studio 2005, but this process works on Visual Studio 2008:

1. Open xyz.cpp along with some other file.
2. Right click on tab header and select new vertical tab group.
3. Left click on that other file in the first tab group.
4. Open xyz.cpp through solution explorer again.

You should now have two instances of file in separate vertical tab groups.

Comment: On my VS2K5 and VS2K8 it just shows the original instances in the second tab for me. 

This is if I double click in Solution Explorer, Drag'n'drop from File Explorer, or via File | Open menu.

Comment: @Simeon - That happens if there isn't another file open (2nd part of step 1.)

Comment: It knows the original file is opened in the other tab group.
Maybe this relates again to the files it permits to duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

To work on two sections of one long file, simply use a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>) or click on the split editor window while you are on the selected tab. The icon is on the top-right of the Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Comment: this answer is for VS Code, not Visual Studio

Comment: Not what was asked, but a good idea for an extension, really. And yes, I won't downvote this answer. Lol.

Comment: Please remove this answer. The question is about [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) ([Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019)).