# Open .aspx file in two windows in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, new-window

I am trying to open the source view of one large .aspx file in two separate windows/tabs in Visual Studio 2013. The "Window > New Window" option is greyed out for this file type.

I am able to do this with other file types including .cs, .css, .js, etc.

I have tried the suggestions in [Open two instances of a file in single Visual Studio session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-single-visual-studio-session) including the registry edit and the custom keyboard shortcut without success. Is there a specific registry hack or some other solution for .aspx files?

Just to clarify, I am not looking to "split" the file. My end goal is to have two copies of the file open in different vertical tab groups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not supported for .aspx files. You can enable the New Window command setting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Languages\Language Services\HTML\Single Code Window Only=0, but opening the second window gives you a blank view.

Comment: FWIW seems like this is still the case in VS2017. Also don't see above registry setting anymore. I guess they've change the registry a bit since then.

Comment: The same thing in VS2019

Comment: still unable to do this in Vs2022 :(