# View 2 methods in same class side by side in Visual Studio Community 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a single class with several long methods.  I want to view one of the methods side by side so I can walk through them line by line like I was walking through a merge process.

If they were in separate classes I could just drag class window to my other monitor but I can't do that within the same class.  I've been copying one of the methods out to notepad for a workaround but I miss my syntax highlighting.

Is there anyway within Visual Studio to do something like this?

Comment: Not sure about within same visual studio, but my idea is, instead of notepad, the file in another instance of visual studio, so you will not face issue with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open two instances of a file in single Visual Studio session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-single-visual-studio-session)

Comment: You are correct BJ Myers.  I saw the post before I posted but didn't think the subject wording was what I was looking for.  I was wrong.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual studio 2013,

Open the class file. In Menu -> "Windows" -> Select "Split"

This will open the same class file in two different panes. If you edit the file, it will be reflected in both.

After you have finished comparing, Menu -> "Windows" -> Select "Remove Split"

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  And it nudged me in the right direction to find this gem.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2011/03/01/split-code-windows-vertically/