# VSCode: Prevent split editor to open same file left & right

Tags: editor, customization, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using VSCode as my main editor, however, when I split the editor into 2, it opens the same file twice, like left & right (see image below).

[image]
Is there any way to prevent it from opening the same file on the next editor? Currently, I have my custom settings and can be copied from [here](https://gist.github.com/genesisneo/4e98d3c0ad1f3e634f474a32d36b9f12).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

command name in Keybindings: `workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup`

command name in Command Palette: `View: Move Editor into Next Group`

default keybinding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

---

command name in Keybindings:`workbench.action.moveEditorToPreviousGroup`

command name in Command Palette: `View: Move Editor into Previous Group`

default keybinding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

[image]

Comment: thank bro! this helps for now. i hope vscode implement layouts in the future where you can set 2-3 columns or rows by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> like on sublime text.

Comment: You can split horizontally or vertically now but not simultaneously. Here's the issue tracking feature request: [grid support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14909).

Comment: All I can say is "why the hell does it work like this at all". Having two instances of the same file open is just the last thing I'd expect. Who writes code on the same file in two places at the same time?

Comment: For Mac, its cmd + control + -> or cmd + control + <-

Comment: @Bosworth99 A little OT, but [some want to see different parts of the same file at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-a-single-visual-studio-session). _I_ don't unless I'm diffing. Don't shoot the messenger. ;^) **More on topic**, how does this answer solve the problem? It moves the file into the previous/next tabset and "erases" the existing instance if a dupe is open, but you'll still get into the `duplicate tabs for same file` situation, right? Is there no way to prevent hitting this state to begin with?