# Move file between vertical panes in visual code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I move an open file between vertical panes in Visual Code?

Is there something like <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>?

Comment: Windows user here. Have no idea what `⌘` + `>` does.

Comment: Are you talking about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304791/vscode-prevent-split-editor-to-open-same-file-left-right/45267954 ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted, thanks @Alex