# Visual Studio - How to open a second window with a designer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I need quite simple help with Visual Studio in which I build my application based on WPF.
By accident, I closed the top window in which the designer was.
Currently, in both windows there is a code, and not as before in a single visual project.I spent over 30 minutes searching for a solution on Google, but I can not find anything. As it is now:
[image: Visual Studio Two Same Windows]

What is expected:

[image: Expected Result]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some clarification in the comments of what you were looking for, once you're in the design view and you've closed the Design/XAML Split, you can reset the window by clicking one of the **split/open** icons in the bottom right hand corner of the window.

With the method you put into your answer, I believe that won't give you the other Designer options (like snapping controls to a grid, disabling/enabling rendering effects/etc) on the window.

[image: Re-open XAML/Designer Split]

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution:

```
1. Select the tab you want two copies of
2. Select menu Window → New Window from the menu.
3. Right click the new tab and select New Vertical Tab Group
```

[Open two instances of a file in a single Visual Studio session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728949/open-two-instances-of-a-file-in-a-single-visual-studio-session)

Comment: Your answer kind of conflicts with your question. Your answer seems like you wanted to open two copies of code, but in your question it looks like you wanted to re-open the designer / XAML split, because you said that the two copies of code is what you have now, and you wanted it to look like the bottom picture -- which has the designer in one window, and the XAML in the other. Which one were you looking for?

Comment: @Chris I wanted to re-open the designer / XAML split, and this method allow me to do so.